# Переделать массив

Tags: java, массивы, строки

Всем привет.
подскажите плиз как из

```
public enum Action{
    actionFilm1,
    actionFilm2,
    actionFilm3,
    actionFilm4
}

Action [] act = Action.values
```

сделать `String []`, так что бы в массиве стрингов были данные `Action`

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Стоит добавлять в метки язык, на котором необходим ответ

Comment: минус за отсутствующую метку языка

Comment: Убрал минус после проставления метки языка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для Java

```
public enum Action {
    actionFilm1, actionFilm2, actionFilm3, actionFilm4;

    private static final String[] valuesNames = initNames();

    private static String[] initNames() {
        final Action[] states = values();
        final String[] names = new String[states.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
            names[i] = states[i].name();
        }
        return names;
    }

    public static String[] names() {
        return valuesNames;
    }
}
```

в нужном месте достаточно вызвать `Action.names()`

Если нужно получать не имена, то вместо `name()` лучше использовать `toString()`

Answer (score 1):

Для C#

Используйте метод [Enum.GetNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx)

```
var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Action));
```